# Any Examples or tutorials out there for using a BaaS such as Parse to handle a web and mobile app?

Tags: web-applications, parse-platform, backend, paas

I want to create a web application that will potentially have a mobile application to accompany it.

The web application will be created with AngularJS. The mobile application has yet to be decided but can most likely be html5 & javascript based.

I figured that since I am using Angular's routing and templating I would be better served just having the backend be a separate REST API. I also don't want to worry about all the issues that come along with creating my own backend (User Auth, Security, HIPAA, PCI, Scalability, etc).

So that is what led me to considering a BaaS like Parse, Cloudmine, or Kinvey.

### So my main questions are.

- Is it possible to make this work?
- Are there any examples or tutorials with this setup.
- Anyone out there that is using this setup? If so then do you like it?

Comment: If HIPAA is a consideration, you probably cannot use any of these BaaS solutions because they are not auditable and lack the integrity required for storing ePHI.  See the following PDFs which are a great start on Required and Addressable Security Specifications of HIPAA (Administrative - http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/adminsafeguards.pdf), (Technical Safeguards - http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/techsafeguards.pdf), (Physical Safeguards - http://www.hhs.gov/ocr/privacy/hipaa/administrative/securityrule/physsafeguards.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

With Parse there are many tutorials which include sample applications. You can also find a lot of code on GitHub for Parse projects.

https://parse.com/tutorials

If you need to comply with HIPAA requirements that is another ballgame entirely. I am not familiar with all of the requirements, but you may want to instead consider other options that these cloud services. Each of them keeps redundant backups and if these backups are compromised that data could get out. If you build the service with Amazon with Amazon RDS (using MySQL, Postgres, or SQL Server) you'd still have to content with audit requirements.

There is a whitepaper available from Amazon which can help.

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2009/04/06/whitepaper-hipaa/

Perhaps there is still a way to use Parse and comply with HIPAA but it is not likely a priority.

https://www.parse.com/questions/hipaa-compliance